# For some reason TFS 2013 stop searching for new workitems, old workitems work good

Tags: tfs

TFS can't found workitems which were created today but it has no problem to find workitems which were created 2-3 monthes ago. It seems that it can't indexing new workitems. We aren't using old template for agile. This problem is actual for all projects.

Comment: This uses the Full-Test Search. Please check the following steps: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142487%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you. On TFS sql server I found table with full-text index and disable Track changing and then enable Track Changes Automatically. It's resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work item search relies on the SQL Server full text search feature. [Check the troubleshooting steps outlined on technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142487%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to ensure that the service is running smoothly on the SQL Server machines that are hosting  the TFS databases.